# Unknown provider: ServiceProvider <- Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angular, I've been trying to solve this for a while and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.
I previously had the service being called on the selector component and it worked fine, but now I have 2 selects and the second is the same list but filtered depending on what is selected on the first, so I have moved it to a filter component which contains both the selects and it doesn't work anymore.

**Old thing-selector.controller.js**

```
export default function ThingSelectorController($scope, ThingService) {
  'ngInject';

  ...

  this.getThings = () => ThingService.find().then((things) => {        
    return things;
  });
}
```

**New filter.controller.js**

```
export default function FilterController($scope, $state, ThingService) {
  'ngInject';
  this.things = [];
  ...

  this.$onInit = () => {
    ThingService.getThings().then((things) => {
       this.things = things;

    });      
  }
```

**filter.component.js**

```
import template from './filter.component.html';
import controller from './filter.controller';

export const FilterComponent = {
  template,
  controller
};

export default FilterComponent;
```

**component.js**

```
imports...

export default angular.module('app.components', [])
.component('thingSelector',  ThingSelectorComponent)
.component('thingWrapper',   ThingWrapperComponent)
.component('filterBox',      FilterComponent)  
...
.name;
```

**apps.js**

```
import { SomethingElseService, ThingService } from './services';

angular.module('myApp', [
  uiRouter,
  uiSelect,
  ngSanitize,
  Components
])
.component('homePage',      HomeComponent)
.component('somethingElsePage', SomethingElseListComponent)

.service('ThingsService',    ThingsService)
.service('SomethingElseService', SomethingElseService)
...
```

**error**

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ThingServiceProvider <- ThingService http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=ThingServiceProvider%20%3C-%20ThingService
    at http://localhost:3000/app.js:7969:13
    at http://localhost:3000/app.js:12403:20
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/app.js:12556:40)
    at http://localhost:3000/app.js:12408:46
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/app.js:12556:40)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:3000/app.js:12580:59)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/app.js:12602:19)
    at $controllerInit (http://localhost:3000/app.js:18135:35)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/app.js:17048:35)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/app.js:16411:14) <ui-view class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: How come your `ThingSelectorController` works fine? Your service is named **ThingsService** but you are using **ThingService**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it was a spelling mistake when I was changing the names from the actual code, which I'm not allowed share. Now it's edited.

Comment: Actually that was the problem, i had called it 'ThingsService' in my app.js and was using 'ThingService' in my controller, thank you for your help.

Comment: you are welcome! Glad to hear you have come through it. :-)